# protobuf grpc relative import path discrepancy in python

Tags: python, grpc-python

I emit the proto compilation into a `generated_code/` directory(say communicator_pb2.py and communicator_pb2_grpc.py). Now, the grpc output imports the python code like so `import communicator_pb2 as communicator__pb2`; without having to modify the import path to `import generated_code.communicator_pb2 as communicator__pb2` or append generated_code to `sys.path`, what is the most legal way to import if I were to import like:

```py
import generate_code.commuinicator_pb2 as communicator_pb2
import generate_code.commuinicator_pb2_grpc as communicator_pb2_grpc
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If the `generated_code` directory is on your `sys.path` either by running `generated_code/..`, by setting `PYTHONPATH`, or via direct manipulation, can't you just use `from generated_code import communicator_pb2` from your application code?

Comment: @RichardBelleville: the problem is `communicator_pb2_grpc.py` imports `communicator_pb2.py` like `import communicator_pb2 as communicator__pb2 `. I know that as long as my `PYTHONPATH` consists of `generated_code/` we are safe here. I was wondering if there was a way to hide this in `__init__.py` or something slightly more elegant. Sorry, I lack some fundamentals here.

Comment: In your `__init__.py`, you might try adding `sys.path.insert(0, PATH_TO_PROTOBUF_DIR)`. This will ensure that the import command you mentioned above will be able to properly resolve the `communicator_pb2` module.

Answer (score 2):

The command `python -m grpc_tools.protoc ... myfile.proto` chooses python package based on relative path to `myfile.proto`. So to use generated_code as package, you can:

```
cp myfile.proto generated_code/myfile.proto
python -m grpc_tools.protoc ... generated_code/myfile.proto
```

Or you can automatically patch the generated file to use relative import:

```sh
sed -i 's/^import .*_pb2 as/from . \0/' generated_code/commuinicator_pb2_grpc.py
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the patch-free solution to work when `myfile.proto` imports another `.proto` file? The relative path solution is breaking down for me in that case

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an elegant solution (probably quite similar to what @Godric was telling in his answer). Suppose you have the following directory structure

```
service
  ├── main.py
  └── generated_code/
       ├── __init__.py       
       ├── communicator.proto
       ├── communicator_pb2.py
       └── communicator_pb2_grpc.py
```

If you compile it the usual way, using `grpc_tools` (see [here](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/#generating-client-and-server-code))

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=service/generated_code --python_out=service/generated_code --grpc_python_out=service/generated_code
```

you would get the following import in `generated_code/communicator_pb2_grpc.py`

```
import communicator_pb2 as communicator__pb2
```

However, when you compile the files with

```
python -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=. --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. generated_code/communicator.proto
```

while sitting in `service/` you obtain the desired result

```
import generated_code.communicator_pb2 as communicator_pb2
```

Comment: I have a project in which my primary `.proto` file (`generated_code/iot-broker.proto` in your example) imports a second file. When I invoke `python -m grpc_tools.protoc` per your recommendation here the import is not found. Do you know of a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry I haven't looked into cross references to other proto files